# Neo4j Deleting nodes on an auto_index index

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a neo4j db with node_auto_indexing and relationship_auto_indexing at true and node_keys_indexable and relationship_keys_indexable with some keys.

I use neo4j 1.9.3 ans SDN 2.3.1.RELEASE

When I try to delete nodes using neoTemplate `neo4jTemplate.delete(t);` I get a read only index exception.

I try to disable auto index like that :

```
neo4jTemplate.getGraphDatabaseService().index().getNodeAutoIndexer().stopAutoIndexingProperty("myprop");
```

or

```
neo4jTemplate.getGraphDatabaseService().index().getNodeAutoIndexer().setEnabled(false);
```

don't work.

Any idea ?